# Big Omega Notation Proving

Tags: complexity-theory

To show that 3n^2 - 25n = Ω(n^2)

```
For n ≥ n / 2           for n ≥ 0
    n – 25/3 ≥ 3n / (2 x 25)    for n ≥ 9
    3n^2 - 25n ≥ 9n^2 / 50      for n ≥ 9

    3n2 - 25n ≥ c·n2 for n ≥ n0 where c=9 / 50 and n0 = 9
Therefore, by definition
      3n2 - 25n = Ω(n2).
```

Above is the proof that 3n^2 - 25n = Ω(n^2).

Why use **n ≥ n / 2**?

How is **n – 25/3 ≥ 3n / (2 x 25)** derived?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do we need n>=n/2. What we *do* need is that n >= 0 => n*3 >= 0 and so we can multiply the first inequality by 3*n on both sides.

(1) n – 25/3 ≥ 3n / (2 x 25) is a simple linear inequality. By doing some transformation we get:

(1) <=> (47/50)*n - 25/3 >= 0 <=> (47/50)*n >= 25/3 <=> n >= (25/3)*(50/47) <=> n >= 1250/141 <=> n >= 8 + 122/141

And from the above we get that this inequality holds true for all n >= 9 > 8 + 122/141. This is just one of the inequalities you can use to prove this big omega notation. Hope my answer helps.